# How to add random hex code command with discord.py?

Tags: python, random, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that would display a random hex code with a command such as `%randhex`, but so far I haven't found any working solutions. Does anyone know how I can do this? I tried doing something like this but with individual codes but there are too many. Here is one way I have tried:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def randcolor(ctx):
    variable = [
        "blue",
        "red",
        "green",
        "yellow",
        "purple",
        "orange",
        "white",
        "black",
        "violet",
        "brown",
        "aqua",
        "cyan",
        "maroon",
        "grey"]
    await client.say(ctx.message.channel, "{}".format(random.choice(variable)))
```

Comment: Title & question intro mention *hex*, the code shows *color*s.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random discord colour from `discord.Colour.random`

```py
colour = discord.Colour.random()
# get colour value
value = colour.value
```

### Reference:

- [Colour](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=colour#discord.Colour)
- [random](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=colour#discord.Colour.random)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nearly the same method with defining a variable with all characters that a hexcode could have (e.g. `variable = "ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"`) and then do `random.sample(variable, 6)` so it gets random 6 characters out of `variable`. You then just have to convert it to hex.

Also I don't know if `ctx.say` or following is existing so I made it like this. Just change it back if it was not right.

This then would look like

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True) 
async def randcolor(ctx): 
    variable = "ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890" 
    await ctx.channel.send(hex("".join(random.sample(variable, 6))))
```

Comment: When I do that, it gives me this error:   File "main.py", line 99, in randhex
    await ctx.channel.send(hex(random.sample(variable, 6)))
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Just understood what .join is for xD edited the answer, hope this works. (If it wants an integer to convert it to hex, you have to add `int("".join(...)))))`)